# Horizontal scroll on UC browser not working due to its Swipe Feature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, single-page-application

I'm stuck with this problem since last few days,
I have a website that's a Single Page Application , built with Angular.

There is a section in the website where I have implemented horizontal scrolling of the divs (carousel type view), that works well on other browser.

However horizontal scrolling fails on UC because it has a built-in feature for swipe over the screen.

Any Idea how can I disable it using JavaScript?

Note : If I go to Settings > Browser Settings > Disable swipe feature, the horizontal works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the container  has the following property set when the page loads (not set by JS on some touch/click event)

```
overflow: scroll;
```

I had the exact problem, I had overflow set to hidden and I was enabling the scroll by a "touch" event. That works well on other browsers but certainly not with UC.

Comment: Saved me! Thanks a lot!